# Creating an Array from a CSV text file and selecting certain parts of the array. in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, arrays, csv

Ive searched over and over the internet for my issue but I havent been able to find / word my searches correctly...

My issue here is that I have a Comma Separated value file in .txt format... simply put, its a bunch of data delimited by commas and text qualifier is separated with ""

For example:

```
"So and so","1234","Blah Blah", "Foo","Bar","","","",""
"foofoo","barbar","etc.."
```

Where ever there is a carriage return it signifies a new row and every comma separates a new column from another.

My next step is to go into VB.net and create an array using these values and having the commas serve as the delimeter and somehow making the array into a table where the text files' format matches the array (i hope im explaining myself correctly :/ )

After that array has been created, I need to select only certain parts of that array and store the value into a variable for later use....

Andthats where my trouble comes in...  I cant seem to get the correct logic as to how to make the array and selecting the certain info out of it..

If any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might perhaps give a more detailed problem description, but I gather you're looking for something like this:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim fileOne As String = "a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1,g1" + Environment.NewLine + _
                           "a2,b2,c2,d2,e2,f2,g2"

    Dim table As New List(Of List(Of String))

    ' Process the file
    For Each line As String In fileOne.Split(Environment.NewLine)
        Dim row As New List(Of String)
        For Each value In line.Split(",")
            row.Add(value)
        Next

        table.Add(row)
    Next

    ' Search the "table" using LINQ (for example)
    Dim v = From c In table _
            Where c(2) = "c1"

    Console.WriteLine("Rows containing 'c1' in the 3rd column:")
    For Each x As List(Of String) In v
        Console.WriteLine(x(0)) ' printing the 1st column only
    Next

    ' *** EDIT: added this after clarification
    ' Fetch value in row 2, column 3 (remember that lists are zero-indexed)
    Console.WriteLine("Value of (2, 3): " + table(1)(2))
End Sub
```

Comment: Im somewhat grasping what you're doing in the example above... To clarify the problem... Im exporting data thats formatted in a table in a third party program, it exports it to a txt file. In the txt file, Columns are separated by commas, anything that qualifies as text is in "" marks, then rows are created everytime there is a carraige return / newline / Line Feed, etc... I want to be able to read that file, extract the data into an array like the one above then for example, find the value of (3,4) in the array and save it into a variable.

Comment: OK. Check out the addition. Hope this helps.

Comment: Everything in the example checks out fine until the line 
`Dim v = From c In table_`
It tells me that the table expression is not a query-able one.
Im guessing im missing a namespace import of some sort.

Comment: Try adding Imports System.Linq

Comment: I tried importing it but it apparently doesnt exist hehe I get a warning Warning 1 Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'System.Linq' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases.

Comment: It seems that you're not able to use LINQ in your project then for some reason, although the error you posted indicates that you're using a recent enough version of .NET. Until you find out what may be causing that, I recommend that you just skip that part of the example, as that had to with querying the "table", not accessing it directly, but it seems you're looking for direct access only.

Comment: After doing some searching, Ive found that System.Linq needd to be referenced in my project file... after going to find that reference, I find that System.Linq, System.Data.Linq, or any variation of that does not exist in that list at all... So Im guessing Linq doesnt exist in my VS2010 at all?

Comment: Ah! It seems I have figured it out!.. In my project settings, It seems that I had to set a reference to the System.Data.Linq.dll file which in turn was in the .NET 4.0 Framework. So i had to change my compile settings to compile using the 4.0 framework and reload my project. After that, I was able to Import System.Linq and the project worked without a hitch!!! Thanks so much!!!